# Can the Finder resume a file copy?

Tags: finder, copy-paste

I know about rsync and how to use it, but sometimes I just want to copy files using the Finder. However, if that fails, I have to do everything all over again, since the Finder does not seem to be able to resume a file copy action. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Finder does what it does and that is do its best not to leave anything unfinished.  If it can't finish a copy it deletes the partials.

You could probably hack together a scriptlet that would let you drag and drop files onto it that would then rsync the file somewhere. You could even make it a folder action.  But it would be limited in where the files end up.

Comment: Well, sometimes the partials are not deleted, because the network connection got severed (happens to some of my SMB mounts). In that case, I would have hoped for a resume. Other filemanagers and tools use the .part extension to indicate partial files that could be resumed.

Answer (score -1):

Finder now supports resume, since Monterey, after you cancel a copy. I'm not sure if it works when the copy is interrupted, eg by a connection drop.
You can find a guide here https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/pause-copying-file-resume-it-later-monterey/
You pretty much get a resume icon next to the greyed out icon of the item whose copy was incomplete.